# Why does routes file point to incorrect controller.Application in play jar after importing Play project to IDEA 13?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, sbt-idea

I've been trying to import a Play2 project in IntelliJ IDEA 13. It seemed to have imported just fine until I tried navigating around the code and realized that the routes file points to the `controller.Application` present in play jar bundled with sbt instead of my file.

I've tried all possible combinations that I could think of:

- Import the checked-out project using IntelliJ IDEA and let it auto-import and resolve dependencies
- Import using play console and then simply opening it in IntelliJ IDEA

However this is not an issue when I create a new play project and the routes file happily points to the right controller.Application.

UPDATE:

My folder structure is like this:
[image]

I tried pulling controllers folder up one level & intellij stopped complaining but I get the error when I view it in browser.

It seems that I'm not configuring it right. I'd really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by setting sources appropriately. Here's how I did it:

- Press Ctrl+Shift+S to open the project properties
- Modules > *your module* > sources (tab)
- Select the following as sources

  - app
  - conf
  - target/scala-2.10/classes_managed
  - target/scala-2.10/src_managed
  - target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running "play idea" in the project directory to refresh the IDEA project file?

Comment: yes, I ran "idea withsources=yes" from the play console